# Inserting on Submit with Association

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am using LinqToSql to map my database in a Winforms C# application.

So far the binding looks fine, but there is a problem with the relationship between two tables.

It is a kind of logger that logs the history of an object. On every log-event there is a Foreign Key linked to the object that caused the event. The problem is that every time I create a row in the log, a new object with a new ID is created in the other table. I just want to use the existing object with the existing ID.

**Inserting the object to the Database**

```
 System.Data.Linq.Table<History> history = dataContext.GetTable<History>();
 History h = new History()
 {
      ReadTime = DateTime.Now,
      MyObject = o
 };

 // The "MyObject" is a reference to an existing object.
 history.InsertOnSubmit(h); 

 // OnSubmit a new MyObject is created with a new ID,
 // instead of referencing the existing one.
 history.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

**The Model Class**

```
[Table(Name = "tbl_History")]
public class History : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private long m_HistoryID;
    private int m_MyObjectFK;
    private EntityRef<MyObject> m_MyObject = new EntityRef<MyObject>();
    private DateTime m_ReadTime;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "HistoryID")]
    public long HistoryID
    {
        get { return this.m_HistoryID; }
        set { this.m_HistoryID = value; }
    }

    [Column(Storage="m_MyObjectFK")]
    public int MyObjectFK 
    {
        get { return this.m_MyObjectFK; }
        set { this.m_MyObjectFK= value; } 
    }

    [Association(Name = "FK_tbl_History_tbl_MyObject",
    IsForeignKey = true, Storage = "m_MyObject", ThisKey = "MyObjectFK")]
    public MyObject MyObject
    {
        get { return m_MyObject.Entity; }
        set 
        { 
            m_MyObject.Entity = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("MyObject");
        }
    }

    [Column(Name = "ReadTime", DbType = "DateTime", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime ReadTime
    {
        get { return m_ReadTime; }
        set
        {
            m_ReadTime = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ReadTime");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785291/why-is-linq-to-sql-entity-association-creating-a-new-duplicate-row-when-insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. It happens because the object I am trying to reference was from an other `DataContext`. In this case it is recognized as a new object. You have to reattach it to the `DataContext` before you use it in the association.

**New Code**

```
System.Data.Linq.DataContext dataContext = new System.Data.Linq.DataContext(connection);

dataContext.GetTable<MyObject>().Attach(o); // Add this line and reattach the MyObject o.

System.Data.Linq.Table<History> history = dataContext.GetTable<History>();
```

A similar question was answered under this link.

[Why is LINQ to SQL entity association creating a new (duplicate) row when inserting a new record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785291/why-is-linq-to-sql-entity-association-creating-a-new-duplicate-row-when-insert)